# MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener doesn't work

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-music-player

For play music from remote server everything works when I use   ***audioPlayer.prepare();***

everything work, but I play song from remote server, so I have to use

```
 audioPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
 audioPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

But when I use this,  music not playing, also I notice that ***MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener*** not calling.

Code:

```
public boolean playAudio(SongDetail mSongDetail) {
        if (mSongDetail == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if ((audioTrackPlayer != null || audioPlayer != null) && MusicPreferance.playingSongDetail != null && mSongDetail.getId() == MusicPreferance.playingSongDetail.getId()) {
            if (isPaused) {
                resumeAudio(mSongDetail);
            }
            return true;
        }
        if (audioTrackPlayer != null) {
            MusicPlayerService.setIgnoreAudioFocus();
        }
        cleanupPlayer(!playMusicAgain, false);
        playMusicAgain = false;
        File file = null;

        try {
            audioPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            audioPlayer.setAudioStreamType(useFrontSpeaker ? AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL : AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            audioPlayer.setDataSource("http://admin.kobyzbook.kz/Audios/2016915164335.mp3");
            audioPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    MusicPreferance.playingSongDetail.audioProgress = 0.0f;
                    MusicPreferance.playingSongDetail.audioProgressSec = 0;
                    if (!MusicPreferance.playlist.isEmpty() && MusicPreferance.playlist.size() > 1) {
                        playNextSong(true);
                    } else {
                        cleanupPlayer(true, true);
                    }
                }
            });

           /* audioPlayer.prepare();
            audioPlayer.start();*/


            audioPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.start();
                }
            });
            audioPlayer.prepareAsync();

            startProgressTimer();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (audioPlayer != null) {
                audioPlayer.release();
                audioPlayer = null;
                isPaused = false;
                MusicPreferance.playingSongDetail = null;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Log

```
09-20 18:56:40.757 7788-7788/com.dmplayer E/MediaPlayer: Attempt to call getDuration without a valid mediaplayer
09-20 18:56:40.757 7788-7788/com.dmplayer E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
09-20 18:56:40.763 7788-7788/com.dmplayer E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
09-20 18:56:40.769 7788-7806/com.dmplayer I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
09-20 18:56:40.770 7788-7806/com.dmplayer I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
09-20 18:56:40.827 7788-7788/com.dmplayer E/MediaPlayer: Attempt to call getDuration without a valid mediaplayer
09-20 18:56:40.828 7788-7788/com.dmplayer E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
09-20 18:56:40.829 7788-7788/com.dmplayer E/MediaPlayer: Attempt to call getDuration without a valid mediaplayer
09-20 18:56:40.830 7788-7788/com.dmplayer E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
09-20 18:56:40.874 7788-7788/com.dmplayer E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
09-20 18:56:40.874 7788-7788/com.dmplayer E/MediaPlayer: stop called in state 0
09-20 18:56:40.874 7788-7788/com.dmplayer E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
09-20 18:56:40.875 7788-7788/com.dmplayer I/System.out: [CDS]close[47061]
09-20 18:56:40.875 7788-7788/com.dmplayer I/NetworkManagementSocketTagger: untagSocket(51)
09-20 18:56:40.897 7788-7788/com.dmplayer W/MediaPlayer: mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
09-20 18:56:40.897 7788-7788/com.dmplayer W/MediaPlayer: mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
09-20 18:56:40.924 7788-7788/com.dmplayer W/MediaPlayer: mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
```

Comment: in your code `audioPlayer.prepare();` in commented.

Comment: Did you get any exception ?

Comment: @vrundpurohit I have two ways to use 1) audioplayer.preoare() or 2)  audioplayer.prepareAsync() ; ,  I choose second way, so I commented audioplayer.preoare().

Comment: @AmanJain I have edited my question and add Log

Comment: Is the file you are referring capable of progressive download? also check the documentation for more insights https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html . Also don't forget to take a look at the logs

Comment: @Pievis Yes file is  capable

Answer (score 0):

What Works for me is below one. I also prepared an app where I have to play video from server

```
private class Player extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {      

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
           checkPreConditions();

        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(params[0]);
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.start();
                        audioTimeInSec = mp.getDuration() / 1000;
//                        Log.e("Time", mp.getDuration() + "  :)");
                    }
                });
//                Log.e("player", "in bg");
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
//            Log.e("player", "in post");
            if (TestViewFragmentNew.this.isDetached() || mediaPlayer == null) return;            
                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.reset();
                        mp.release();
                      });          
        }
    }
```

Check PreCondition method

```
 private void checkPreConditions(){
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                    }
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                    mediaPlayer= null;
                }
                }
```

Where you want to use it use like below :

```
String URL = "http://admin.kobyzbook.kz/Audios/2016915164335.mp3;

            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);           
                playerService = new Player(objj);
                playerService.execute(URL);
```